# use jquery css to change image size on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I've got an html table that contains videos and images in the list. If you click on any row it plays a video or shows the image in a div.

I also have a size change link to adjust the size of the video or image when clicked.

```
<div id="player" style="display:block;width:320px;height:240px;background-image:url(http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/Circle_Red.png)"></div>
<a id="toggleres" href="#">Change to 640x480</a>
<table id="webcam-table" class="pretty">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Date Created</th>
                    <th>Length</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="videorow" data-url=http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Audi-A1.jpg>
                        <td>
                            testimages 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            13 Jun 2013 22:01:37 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            1sec    
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr class="videorow" data-url=http://metalstate.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/10-mclaren-p1-cars-to-wait-for-jpg_235623.jpg>
                        <td>
                            testimages 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            13 Jun 2013 22:01:37 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            1sec    
                        </td>
                    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can see any image or play any video when you click the row in the table. At any point you can change the resolution (size) by clicking the link.

```
    jQuery('#toggleres').click(function(event) { 
        if (jQuery('#toggleres').text() == "Change to 320x240"){
            jQuery(this).html("Change to 640x480");
            jQuery('#player').css({'width':'320px', 'height':'240px', 'background-image': 'url(http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/Circle_Red.png)'});
        }
        else{
            jQuery(this).html("Change to 320x240");
            jQuery('#player').css({'width':'640px', 'height':'480px', 'background-image': 'url(http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/Circle_Red.png)'});

        }
    });

jQuery("#webcam-table").on("click", "tr.videorow > td", function(e) {
        var parser = document.createElement('a');
        parser.href = theUrl;
            //the right host, therefore it is an image
        if (parser.hostname == "myhost.com")
        {
            jQuery("#player").css("background", "url('" + theUrl + "')");
        }
        else
        {
            flowplayer("player", "js/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.12.swf", {
                clip: {
                    url: theUrl,
                    provider: 'rtmp'
                },
                plugins: {
                    rtmp: {
                        url: "js/flowplayer/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.10.swf",
                        netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://'+window.location.host+'/recordings'
                    }
                }
            });
        }
});
```

This has worked great for videos without any special consideration, because it opens in a player that will adjust to the div size and keeps playing. Images are different. If you click on a image then try to change the size it just gets reset to the original background. I realize that is exactly what the code is doing but it was just great for videos.

I'm struggling to figure out how I can make this work for both videos and images. Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LFBHv/4/)** that illustrates the behavior (at least for images).

Note that the #toggleres click event needs to exist. Someone should be able to toggle the size of the background image without ever clicking a row in the table. In other words if no image or video is clicked the main background placeholder image needs to be there.

To summarize the expected behavior:

1. A background image (320x240) is shown. Someone clicks on the the change resolution link and it will expand to (640x480) - this is currently working with the code below
2. If someone clicks on a row in the table (which could be a video or image) it will change the background image (whether it is 320x240 or 640x480) - this is currently working with the code below
3. If someone clicks another row in the table that image/video will change the background image - this mostly works but if you play a video you can't click another row with an image, it doesn't reset/remove the player
4. Anytime there is a image or video on the screen (after clicking a table row) you can click on the change resolution to make the video or image bigger/smaller - this doesn't work as it will always reset to the background image (the fiddle illustrates this)

Comment: Could explain a bit more what the intended behavior is?

Comment: @Grampa Added a summary of expected behavior. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to remove the `, 'background-image': 'url(http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/Circle_Red.png)'` part in the javascript (in both places where it appears). This should do the trick for point 4 of your summary. Not sure about point 3 though - I need to see the code that adds the player to the page in order to determine how to remove it.

Comment: I added the video player code. The difficulty with this is that it is using flowplayer which stays open. I need to reset this player somehow...